# keeping data elsewhere and only save it when user has confirm their Email

Tags: java

I am developing a java web application using JSF and I will like to find out if it is possible for me to hold (and save) user information in an different location, say a file, and then when the user confirm their email before the date is save to the database.

I don't yet understand certain thing. What I intend to know is if it is possible to use serialization for this problem.

Comment: How about having a field in the database to indicate if they have confirmed their email?

Comment: If this data must be alive per user session by browser client, save it on session, if it needs to be shared among several browsers, save it on database temporary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the user on the database before it has confirmed its email.
You need to set him a status NOT_CONFIRMED which can be transformed to CONFIRMED.

Until he has confirmed, you should not allow the application login for users which are found, but having an illegal status like NOT_CONFIRMED.

There's no benefit in saving the user data somewhere else for most usecases.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 proposes the local storage API which permits storing data in the browser of your client. Since the user is not logged, you'll be unable to recognize him from another computer, so it's fair that the data will be available only on the browser he wrote it in.

You can then transfer the data to your server once the user is connected (htis feature is used by Google documents, offline gmail etc...). If you're using GWT, a java API is available to access the native browser API, otherwise, you'll need some js coding

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi
http://1vu.fr